# NodeJS Express: Pattern for common data elements on every page

Tags: node.js, caching, express

Is there a recommended pattern for page elements that are persistent and common across all pages on a site? For instance, a "total units sold" on the top of every page. You would cache that value and update the cache every hour or so, but where would you actually retrieve this value and pass it to the view in the express web request?

In PHP you have to use a key-store, but since node is persistent across requests it seems like you would keep the value in memory, but where?

A couple thoughts:

1) In the app object from express() and pass to view with render. I think app.locals is designed for this, but app.locals can't be accessed from within the route handler.

2) Use a cache and pass it to    view with render - I don't like that I    have to explicitly call    cache.getCommonValues in every route    handler, extend the object, and    pass it again in render.

3) Hack into the renderer and extend every data    object with common    stuff - Elegant maybe, but how to access the    values to update them    with a cronjob or when you just want to check    one in the route    handler. Also not sure exactly how to hack the renderer, mustache in this case...

4) Store it in the session - Might get big,    hard to update reliably.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: IMO #1 hacking is worth any effort. #2 & #4 causes an unnecessary bloat and lags. #3 is much more difficult to implement, so the simpler, the better.

Answer (score 2):

`app.locals` is fine for this, and yes it is available in the route handler via `res.app.locals`. Both the request and the response have access to each other as well as the app instance.